# What's different from the Spring lang annotations and jsr305 meta-annotations?

Tags: spring, annotations, jsr305

For example, `org.springframework.lang.NonNull` and `javax.annotation.Nonnull`. Why Spring does repeat work? What does Spring have to do it?